# Waterfall with minimum cap for each column

Tags: r, matrix, max

I have a matrix with random values:

```
set.seed(1)
n_rows <- 6
n_cols <- 5
mat_random <- matrix(runif(n = 30,0.04,0.06),n_rows,n_cols)

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] 0.04531017 0.05889351 0.05374046 0.04760070 0.04534441
[2,] 0.04744248 0.05321596 0.04768207 0.05554890 0.04772228
[3,] 0.05145707 0.05258228 0.05539683 0.05869410 0.04026781
[4,] 0.05816416 0.04123573 0.04995398 0.04424285 0.04764776
[5,] 0.04403364 0.04411949 0.05435237 0.05303348 0.05739382
[6,] 0.05796779 0.04353114 0.05983812 0.04251110 0.04680698
```

And I have a cap for each columns except for the last column of 0.05:

```
capped_value <- 0.05
```

I want to create another matrix which would cap the values row wise and accumulate the exceeding value till the final column. Here is an example with for:

```
mat_new <- mat_random

for(rw in 1:n_rows){
  for(cl in 1:n_cols){

      if(cl!=n_cols){
        mat_new[rw,cl+1] <- mat_new[rw,cl+1]+ifelse(mat_new[rw,cl]>capped_value,mat_new[rw,cl]-capped_value,0)
        mat_new[rw,cl] <- ifelse(mat_new[rw,cl]>capped_value,capped_value,mat_new[rw,cl])
      }  

  }
}

[1,] 0.04531017 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.05557908
[2,] 0.04744248 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.05416922
[3,] 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.05839809
[4,] 0.05000000 0.04939988 0.04995398 0.04424285 0.04764776
[5,] 0.04403364 0.04411949 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.06477966
[6,] 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.05065513
```

Is it possible to do it somehow in an efficient way?

I would very much appreciate for your help.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: I edited the text with a solution using for loops. But it looks ugly as hell.

Answer (score 0):

We can remove one of the loops to make it more efficient

```
m1 <- mat_random
for(j in head(seq_len(ncol(m1)), -1)) {
  m1[, j + 1] <-  m1[, j + 1] <- m1[, j + 1] + ((m1[,j] - 
           capped_value) * (m1[,j] > capped_value))
  m1[, j][m1[,j] > capped_value] <- capped_value
}

identical(m1, mat_new)
#[1] TRUE
```